# Pressing emoji shortcut prints out letter "e"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emoji

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with emoji shortcut set up in ibus. Pressing the shortcut prints out a letter e with underscore. I've been trying to change the shortcut to another combination but it still behaves the same.